# Rails 6 Nested Attributes, Uniquness Validation Failing on destroyed records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, nested-attributes, accepts-nested-attributes, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I am facing issue in validating nested attributes uniquness. I have 2 models

```
#model : CompanyStore
class CompanyStore < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :company_stores_brands, dependent: :destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :company_stores_brands, allow_destroy: true
end


class CompanyStoreBrand < ApplicationRecord
  validates_uniqueness_of :brand_id
end
```

brand_id should be unique for **CompanyStoreBrand** . If I remove brand from one store and assign to another store it is throwing an exception because it is not destroyed. Below is params that I am sending

```
    "company_stores_attributes"=>[
{"id"=>1, "store_id"=>446, "company_stores_brands_attributes"=>[{"id"=>1, "_destroy"=>1, "brand_id"=>69258}]}, 
{"id"=>3, "store_id"=>472, "company_stores_brands_attributes"=>[{"brand_id"=>69258}]}]

params.require(:company).permit(company_stores_attributes: [:id, :store_id, :_destroy,{ company_stores_brands_attributes: %i[id brand_id _destroy] }])
```

I have seen lot of solutions on stackoverflow but some of them are inefficient Or this criteria is not supported. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Are yous sure you are permitting the `:destroy` in controller params ?

Comment: @maya_nk99 Yes , also added in question